How to successfully build non-SDK project that references SDK projects
I have a solution that contains few projects of different FW versions (4, 4.6.* ,4.7., 4.8.) and different project file types (SDK and "old" type).
I have a specific project (Call it NonSDKProject) which has project file which is not SDK.
There are some base rules, I have to work acording to:

I have no option to change it to sdk style.
I have to build this project with msbuild cli command

The project has references to other projects, formatted as SDK projects.
When I try to build the NonSDKProject using msbuild cli command, few of the SDK projects fails, claiming:
"The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MsBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format."

I've tried adding the xmlns in the (SDK) project tag - but it doesn't help.
I also tried to build the SDK project before the Non-SDK project, using dotnet build cli command - they all built successfully, but the non-SDK project still fails
So - to make a long story short:
How can I make a non-SDK project that must be built with msbuild when has references to an SDK projects - built successfully ?

This doesn't make sense. I'll explain why. But can you produce a minimal example that demonstrates the issue? MSBuild v15 and newer supports both "legacy style" and "SDK style" projects. A solution can mix projects of both types. Each project is built in its own context so there shouldn't be any issues with mixing project types. The reported error message sounds like an old (pre-v15) version of MSBuild is encountering an SDK style project. This could be a bug or in could be a very specific circumstance. Regardless I'm happy to try to reproduce the issue if you can provide a minimal example.

Jonathan Dodds - You are correct - I was using an old version of MSBuild
